# How to divide image into several parts? Tilemap

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game, where map of the world will be created from blocks called Tiles. All Tiles are saved in single PNG file, similar to that posted below:

[image]

I need to divide this image and store all those blocks in memory separately, so I could draw those Tiles on screen in desired order.

What's the best way to do that, so it will be working well in every web browser?

Answer (score 6):

simply look at the drawImage function of the canvas : when using all its arguments it allready allows to copy selectively a part of the image.

```
var tileIndex   = 3; // index of the tile within the texture image 
var tileWidth=16, tileHeight = 16;
var tilePerLine = 6;
var offsetX     = (tileIndex % tilePerLine)*tileWidth;  
var offsetY     = Math.floor(tileIndex / tilePerLine) * tileHeight;

ctx.drawImage(thisImage, offsetX, offsetY, tileWidth, tileHeight, x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some useful frameworks like [Pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/). But if you like to avoid canvas or huge frameworks, you can also work with CSS.

```css
.tile {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO5jy.png);
    float: left;
}

.tile.tile-floor {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.tile.tile-wall { 
    background-position: -64px 0px;
}

.tile.tile-blue {
    background-position: -192px -192px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile tile-blue"></div>
<div class="tile tile-floor"></div>
<div class="tile tile-wall"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your map on [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) It supports TMX map format that you can then render in your game with some of the HTML renders described here [HTML 5 TMX support](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps) You have to scroll a little to find the HTML list.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example, may be this will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/HmpGx/

```
(function( $, window ) {

  var _defaults = {
    x : 3, // tiles in x axis
    y : 3, // tiles in y axis
    gap: 2
  };

  $.fn.splitInTiles = function( options ) {

    var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {

      var $container = $(this),
          width = $container.width(),
          height = $container.height(),
          $img = $container.find('img'),
          n_tiles = o.x * o.y,
          wraps = [], $wraps;

      for ( var i = 0; i < n_tiles; i++ ) {
        wraps.push('<div class="tile"/>');
      }

      $wraps = $( wraps.join('') );

      // Hide original image and insert tiles in DOM
      $img.hide().after( $wraps );

      // Set background
      $wraps.css({
        width: (width / o.x) - o.gap,
        height: (height / o.y) - o.gap,
        marginBottom: o.gap +'px',
        marginRight: o.gap +'px',
        backgroundImage: 'url('+ $img.attr('src') +')'
      });

      // Adjust position
      $wraps.each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        $(this).css( 'backgroundPosition', -pos.left +'px '+ -pos.top +'px' );
      });

    });

  };

}( jQuery, window ));

$('div').splitInTiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concept of "image sprite" using css to do this.

IF your game has 4 x 4 grid, then you will have to create 16 `<div>` and each div set the `background-image: url(image.jpg)` and `background-position:-left -top`.
Please read about `background-position` to understand it better. (http://www.csslessons.com/)

Then all you have to do is keep changing the `<div>` position when the user clicks of the tiles.