# Split background image with 3D thickness effect

Tags: jquery, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I want to split background image. For example original image like this
[image: Original 3D rotated image]

and I want an effect like this:

[image: slit image in 3 and give a thickness effect]

This is my code

```
<style>
    div{

    -webkit-transform: skewY(175deg); 
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 10px;
    background-image: url(Chrysanthemum.jpg);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-origin: content-box;
    }
</style>
<div></div>
```

But I can't find any way how to split this background with the same thickness effect with CSS or jQuery.

Comment: you could do something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16935679/2633871

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This answer provides single element solutions only**

A 2D solution would be to just use the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to imitate the gaps. You only need to [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) them and give them the proper distance to the border with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

To make it look more 3D, you can use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) `perspective()` in combination with `rotateY()` instead of `skewY()`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
  margin: 50px 10px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/600/200);
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
div:before {
  left: calc(33% - 5px);
}
div:after {
  right: calc(33% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

To achieve a very simple 3D effect, you can add a `border-left` to the div and a `border-right` to the pseudo elements. With additionally applying a white top and bottom border and making the right border semi-transparent, the pseudo elements even give an 3D feeling. Unfortunately that is not possible with the main element. But here you can at least play around with the border transparency.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
  margin: 50px 10px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/600/200);
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
div:before {
  left: calc(33% - 7px);
}
div:after {
  right: calc(33% - 7px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: looking good..just want to one thing more if you look image every split image take side width also. How can we do this is it possible?

Comment: The thickness will be hard to create... maybe you can do something similar to [this tutorial](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/rectangular-prism.html). But you will need a lot of HTML elements and CSS manipulation...

Answer (score 25):

Here is a 3D approach to cut the image in 3 parts and make the thickness effect. 
It is responsive and relies on:

- 3d transforms for the rotation of the image and the thickness effect
- the "padding technique" to keep the aspect ratio of the elements
- pseudo elements to make the thikness of each part of the image
- background image and background-position

Demo of a **[3d rotated and thick image](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/QKapxJ)**.

Output:
[image: image cut into 3 rotated parts and 3D thickness]

```css
body{perspective:1000px;}
.imgWrap{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  margin:5% auto;
  padding-bottom:39%;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.imgWrap > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:30.3%;height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/FhZxJJp.jpg');
  background-size:auto 100%;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  outline: 1px solid transparent; /* prevent jagged edges in firefox */
}
.imgWrap .left  { left: 0;     background-position:   3% 0; }
.imgWrap .center{ left:34.83%; background-position: -97% 0; }
.imgWrap .right { left:69.66%; background-position:-197% 0; }
.imgWrap > div:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:100%;
  width:10%; height:100%;
  background:inherit;
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
}
.imgWrap .left:before  { background-position:     0%   0; }
.imgWrap .center:before{ background-position: -1001.3% 0; }
.imgWrap .right:before { background-position: -2001.4% 0; }
```

```html
<div class="imgWrap">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes for browser support. For more info, see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).*

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that rely on  **one element**.

The idea is to use multiple background to create different layers above the intial image in order to:

- Create the gap between each part of the image using white color (or same color as the main background).
- Create the shadow for each part.
- Create the thickness effect by using a transparent color.

Then we do a rotation with perspective in order to have the 3D illusion.

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  max-width:600px;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background:
  /*
    1: The bottom shadow
    2: A small triangle at the bottom left corner for the 3D effect
    3: A small triangle at the top    left corner for the 3D effect
    4: The left side shadow
    5: White color to create the separation between each part
  */
  
  /* First part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(24deg,transparent 54%,#aaa 57%)          0px  100%/30px 16px border-box border-box,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 10px 100%/8px 3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    10px 0   /8px 3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         10px 0   /8px 100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               0 0      /10px 100%,
  /* Second part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)          130px 100%/10px 16px,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 140px 100%/8px  3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    140px 0   /8px  3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         140px 0   /8px  100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               130px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* Third part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)          260px 100%/10px 16px,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%) 270px 100%/8px  3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#fff 52%)    270px 0   /8px  3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))         270px 0   /8px  100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                               260px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* Main background */
  url(https://picsum.photos/400/200/?image=1015) 0 0/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
</div>
```

[image: 3D background image with perspective]

To better understand the puzzle use different colors for each gradient:

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  max-width:600px;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background:
  /*
    1: The bottom shadow
    2: A small triangle at the bottom left corner for the 3D effect
    3: A small triangle at the top    left corner for the 3D effect
    4: The left side shadow
    5: White color to create the separation between each part
  */
  
  /* First part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(24deg,transparent 54%,red 57%)           0px  100%/30px 16px border-box border-box,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,blue 52%) 10px 100%/8px 3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,black 52%)   10px 0   /8px 3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(pink,pink)                               10px 0   /8px 100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(green,green)                             0 0      /10px 100%,
  /* Second part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,red 51%)           130px 100%/10px 16px,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,blue 52%) 140px 100%/8px  3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,black 52%)   140px 0   /8px  3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(pink,pink)                               140px 0   /8px  100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(green,green)                             130px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* Third part */
  /*1*/ linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,red 51%)           260px 100%/10px 16px,
  /*2*/ linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,blue 52%) 270px 100%/8px  3px,
  /*3*/ linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,black 52%)   270px 0   /8px  3px,
  /*4*/ linear-gradient(pink,pink)                               270px 0   /8px  100%,
  /*5*/ linear-gradient(green,green)                             260px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* Main background */
  url(https://picsum.photos/400/200/?image=1015) 0 0/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
</div>
```

---

You can optimize the code using `mask` to have transparency:

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  max-width:600px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border-left:30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background:
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 65%,#aaa 67%)   0  100%/30px 16px border-box border-box,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  0 0   /8px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)   130px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  140px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                        130px 0   /10px 100%,
  /* */
  linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)   260px 100%/10px 16px,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))  270px 0   /8px  100%,
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)                        260px 0   /10px 100%,
  
  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/400/200) center/cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#fff 51%)  160px 100%/10px 16px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)  290px 100%/10px 16px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 0     50%/160px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 0 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 0 100%/160px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 170px 50%/120px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 140px 0/150px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 140px 100%/150px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 300px 50%/130px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 270px 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 270px 100%/160px 8px;
  mask:
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#fff 51%)  160px 100%/10px 16px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 35%,#aaa 51%)  290px 100%/10px 16px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 0     50%/160px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 0 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 0 100%/160px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 170px 50%/120px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 140px 0/150px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 140px 100%/150px 8px,
     
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 300px 50%/130px calc(100% - 16px),
     linear-gradient(147deg,transparent 21px,#fff 22px) 270px 0/160px 8px,
     linear-gradient(30deg,transparent 19px,#fff 20px) 270px 100%/160px 8px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
</div>
```

[image: 3D transparent background image with perspective]

Comment: Please add (if possible) comments in the snippet code \ In the first comment, I meant that people did not appreciate the answer as it was worth it